# Durability of a computer with a chip from China/Japan

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

A computer contains a chip either from China with probability $p \in (0,1)$ or from Japan with probability $1-p$. The durability of such a computer (in years) is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$ respectively $\mu$ if the chips originate from China/Japan.

Now I want to determine the cumulative distribution function and expected value of $T$ where $T$ is the durability of a random computer.

So my approach was to define $T:=T_C \cdot p\,+\,T_J\cdot(1-p)$ where $T_C$ and $T_J$ are the durabilities of a computer with a chip from China/Japan. Do I have to formulate the cdf for $T \sim \exp(p\lambda+(1-p)\mu) ?$
Might be totally wrong, a hint on how to begin would be much appreciated.

Comment: Despite being written in German, this http://www.exponentialverteilung.de/vers/beweise/faltung_2.html may help (convolution of two exponential).

Comment: If you add 2 exponential distributions, you don't get an exponential distribution, you get a Gamma distribution

Comment: So the cdf is $ F_T(t)= \frac{\lambda \mu}{\lambda - \mu} \cdot e^{-\lambda t} \cdot (e^{(\lambda - \mu)t} -1) $ or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe or do I still have to integrate it?

Comment: Exactly, this is the PDF.

Comment: Hm when integrating it I get $\infty$..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cdf is given by

\begin{align*}P(T>x)&=P(T>x\text{ and China})+P(T>x\text{ and Japan})\\
&=P(T>x|\text{China})P(\text{China})+P(T>x|\text{Japan})P(\text{Japan})\\
&=pF_\lambda(x)+(1-p)F_\mu(x),\end{align*}
where $F_\lambda(x)=P(T>x|\text{China})$ is just the cdf for $\lambda$.

So the right thing to do is to just work out the two individual cdfs and take a weighted average. (This is not the same as averaging the parameter and then taking the cdf of that.)

Comment: Ok thank you. So what I ended up with is $P(T>x)=p(-e^{-\lambda T} +1 )
 +(1-p) (-e^{-\mu T} +1)$. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Yes, that looks good. You meant $x$ rather than $T$ on the RHS presumably.

Comment: Yes, typos. Thanks, will award the bounty in 20 hours!

Comment: A last question:
So the expected value is $E(X)= \int_0^\infty x f(x) \, dx =\int_0^\infty x (p \lambda e^{-\lambda x} + (1-p) \mu e^{-\mu x}) \, dx = {p \over \lambda} + {(1-p) \over \mu}$?

Comment: Yes , that's right